How to change Azure build directory when using a Github repository
I want to deploy a NodeJS API using a GitHub repository, the problem is that the directory of my API I want to deploy is located at ./anti-scraping-backend. Azure doesn't seem to give a simple way to change the directory. My yaml file is the following:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - anti-scraping-api

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: Change directory to anti-scraping-backend
        run: cd ./anti-scraping-backend 

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ I DON'T THINK I CAN SHOW IT HERE }}
          tenant-id: ${{ I DON'T THINK I CAN SHOW IT HERE  }}
          subscription-id: ${{ I DON'T THINK I CAN SHOW IT HERE }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'anti-scraping-api'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ./anti-scraping-backend

The Azure logs say it's trying to build on the root, so it's of course failing.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/Scraping-Anti-Scraping-Techniques/Scraping-Anti-Scraping-Techniques/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/Scraping-Anti-Scraping-Techniques/Scraping-Anti-Scraping-Techniques/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

I tried changing package to package: ./anti-scraping-backend also tried to run the step command run: cd ./anti-scraping-backend 

You can use working-directory: in you .yml file to define directory to run commands.

If you the want to deploy a specific directory using GitHub action you need to use working-directory.
My Directory :
Root/
|   
| - backend/
| - react_app/
| | - public/
| | - src/
| | - ...
| | - package.json


main_directorygitapp.yml:
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - directorygitapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
        working-directory: react_app/

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'directorygitapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }}

OUTPUT:


